# chunk size error when import blockchain file using monero-blockchain-import

Tags: synchronization

I am importing monero blockchain using this command:

`./monero-blockchain-import --verify 0 --input-file ./blockchain.raw`

I am getting error:

`Aborting: chunk size exceeds buffer size`

more details here:
https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/2031

Answer (score 0):

The issue is a corrupt blockchain file, which is now better handled (as of September 2017). If anyone is seeing this with a newer version of the Monero software, you're likely running into a separate issue